# Start and receive the result of service in another apk file without using AIDL

Tags: android, service, ipc

Assume I have 2 application: A.apk and B.apk. Applcation B only consists of 1 background service and has no UI. The pplication A.apk want to call the service in application B.apk, transmit some data and receive the result from application B.apk.

I know there is 1 techniques is using AIDL. But because I just want to perform IPC, but do not need to handle multithreading, it is not necessary to use AIDL.

Could you please tell me is there a technique to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Activity A call `startService()` with data you want to transmit into Service B. 
In Service B handle this call in `onStartCommand()`. Then after handling send custom broadcast to Activity A. The broadcast receiver must be registered in this Activity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, according to Android developer: "Usually, a started service performs a single operation and does not return a result to the caller." How can start service return a result?

Comment: it doesn't provide any result. The result will come in broadcast